# how to print text in selected text box on windows

Tags: python, winapi

hi i have a code that recognizes my voice and prints it in python shell.

now i want it to print text in the selected text box , what should i do?

**code is :**

```
import speech_recognition as sr


def start():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("listening started")
        audio = r.listen(source)

    WIT_AI_KEY = "what ever"
    try:
        print("Wit.ai thinks you said " + r.recognize_wit(audio, key=WIT_AI_KEY))
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Wit.ai could not understand audio")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results from Wit.ai service; {0}".format(e))
    start()
start()
```

Comment: What selected text box?

Comment: any selected text box that cursor is in it!

Comment: Start reading up on [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684021(v=vs.85).aspx) then.

Comment: When implementing a keyboard replacement, calling [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) is likely the right way to go.

Comment: how should i send text into text box using python and win32 then?

Comment: By using UI Automation. But if you want to produce input into whatever has focus that's a different matter.

Comment: thats what i want :(